# How does ruby's .min and .max method work, and what is the time complexity when using those methods to find min or max value in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, max, time-complexity, min

Context:

I was looking at an algorithms problem to determine max_stock_profit when given an array of stock prices. I was trying to determine the time complexity of said method, and encountered a `.min` used on an array within the `each` method. This led me to asking the question titled in this post.

Generally speaking, when simply looking at the `.min` or `.max` method on an array of length 1,000,000 for example, wouldn't running `.min` or `.max` on the array require linear time O(n) to determine a min or max value, where n is the length of the array?..

If so, then based on the example code shown below, by running `.min` or `.max` method within an `each` method, wouldn't the time complexity be O(n^2) since it needs to run another iteration within the `each` method to determine min value? I think the code snippet should be running at O(n) time but my lack of understanding of how `.min` and `.max` works is what's causing great confusion.

Is it because since `.min` is invoked on an array containing only 2 values, it is okay assume that line of code operates in constant time O(1)? Any help to clear my misunderstanding of what's going on would be appreciated. Thanks.

Example code snippet:

```
stock_prices = [5, 7, 2 ,4, 9, 1, 8]
min_price = stock_prices[0]
max_profit = 0

stock_prices.each do |current_price|
    min_price = [min_price, current_price].min
    potential_profit = current_price - min_price  
    max_profit = [max_profit, potential_profit].max
end
```

Comment: What's being done with the `etc...`?  That may be relevant to why the person who wrote this didn't just say `min_price = stock_prices.min`.  For instance, maybe it's a sequential process and the logic is premised on the lowest stock price seen so far.

Comment: yes it is a sequential process and is based on the lowest stock price when comparing the initial min price and current price. But I am confused about what the time complexity of this code snippet, specifically when implementing .min and .max within .each method. I thought by using .min, it requires another iteration within .each, which leads me to believe the time complexity takes longer than O(n)?

Comment: I believe the code here is O(n), that is it is linear based on the length of stock prices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.min` and `.max` operations in the `each` are being applied to arrays with only 2 elements, so each is an O(1) operation. Changing n, the number of elements in `stock_prices`, won't change the amount of time to find either the `.min` or `.max` in each iteration, they are independent of n.  Consequently, the entire block is O(n).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Generally speaking, if the array was larger, say of length 1000, the min/max method would take linear time since it has iterate through each element correct? I'm asking because ill have to be more careful when liberally using .min or max within another iterator if I wanted to optimize runtime

Comment: `min` is linear in the size of the array *it is iterating over*. BUT! In this case, the size of the array that `min` is iterating over is bounded by a constant (2 in the original example, 1000 in your hypothetical). *Whenever* a function is bounded by a constant, it is in O(1). (Just plug it into the definition of Big-Oh and you'll see.) Bottom line: always be careful to rigorously define what "n" is, when talking about time complexity as a function of n.

Comment: @GeorgeV. No, because it's not iterating through the original array.  The `each` block creates temporary arrays containing only 2 elements, so the amount of work per iteration has nothing to do with the original array length.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ok. For clarification, if I performed this operation:

Comment: @JörgWMittag Whoops, didn't know pressing ENTER would post comment...
Ok. For clarification, if I performed .max on arr in this example : 

        arr = Array.new(100) { rand(1000) } ;
        arr.max 

...Invoking the `.max` method to find the max value in `arr` would be constant time because the length of array, specified as 100, is constant, correct? 
Assuming the way `.max` method works is it looks at every element in the array to find and return the max value, in this case it is still considered constant time because n is known.

Comment: @pjs I now understand your answer. `n` is independent from the .min and .max operation conducted within the each method, and since `.min` and `.max` is invoked on an array that is always bounded by a constant of 2 elements, each operation is constant. Even if `.min` and `.max` is invoked on an array containing 10000 elements, the operation is still constant because the size of the array that `min` is called on is known.

Comment: @GeorgeV. Correct, but it also illustrates that constant time operations can have honking big constants. But if you do a honking big constant time operation for each of the of the elements in an array of size N you are doing a honking big constant amount of work N times, which is still O(N).  Remember, at the heart of it big-O notation tells you how a problem ***scales*** with N, not how much time it takes for a fixed value of N.